# Speech Recognizer not working for Other language android

Tags: locale, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am working on speech recognization which is working only for english and hindi but if i am working on other language like bengali and urdu etc for that it is not working. code written by me.

locale may be "ur" for urdu and "bn for bengali"

recognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);

recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, locale);

recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, true);

recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS, 1000);

recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);

recognizerIntent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.DICTATION_MODE", true);